# How to use Mathjax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I can't seem to find instruction anywhere on how to use Mathjax or whatever it is called to correctly format equations etc. I remember seeing a list but can't locate it on the site

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/804/2451

Answer (score 2):

Mathjax is pretty similar to Latex I believe. I would recommend learning Latex since it is more comprehensive and will be more helpful in the long run. However, it is not really necessary. Math SE has good references regarding Mathjax

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Well, MathJax is just an implementation of TeX. There should only be a few differences between it and LaTeX. Probably most notably that we have to use \$\$ and \$\$\$\$ instead of \(\) and \[\].